# How can I simulate a button press in Swift iOS8 using code

Tags: ios, button, swift, ios8

How can I simulate a button press within a View in using Swift.  I'm trying to get Calendar permissions and have a function setup to check this authorization when I click the start button this currently runs

```
@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
//loads prompt to "Allow" or "Don't Allow" calendar permissions
eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: handler)

//checkAuth function looks at calendar authorization to get current status 
and then acts accordingly to dismiss View or load Privacy Settings
checkAuth()

}
```

I need to be able to simulate a button press of the Start button to trigger the start() func once again.  The only thing I've found so far seems to be in Objective-C

`[buttonObj sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

I'm not familiar with Obj-C and need a way to implement this in Swift if possible...Thanks

Answer (score 29):

The Swift translation of:

```
[buttonObj sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

is:

```
button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

and it should in fact simulate a button push.

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3

`button.sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)`

Swift 4

`button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)`

Answer (score 1):

Try calling your IBAction function:

```
self.start(self)
```